# PGAdmin4 - import success no data imported

Tags: csv, import, pgadmin

i am new to SQL and studying - so far i hate it - i am hopeful this will change.

The course content has a file, which was a CSV - imported to excel to edit, saved as an excel. I am importing to pgadmin - no error. but no data either.

is it because it was opened in excel?

IM LOOSING MY MIND

Ive googled for similar errors and nothing :(

Comment: *... saved as an excel.* to me means you saved as Excel format(xlsx) and that is not a CSV file so it cannot be imported.  If you indeed save as a CSV file then FYI Excel != CSV.

Comment: Have try some attemps, e.q. close the opened filr and try it again? Some lines of code would also help other users to diagnose the possible problems and give solution.